# Pasar parametros en addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una duda con JS que gustaria que alguno me ayudara.

En mi aplicación hay un panel para agregar un producto a una tabla lo cual se realiza mediante un boton. Este boton posee un evento onclick que realiza la inserccion de la informacion del producto en la tabla. El codigo es el siguiente:

CODIGO BOTON:

```
<a class="agregar" onclick="agregarProducto('<?php echo $producto['ID_Producto']?>', '<?php echo $producto['Nombre_Producto']?>', '<?php echo $producto['PrecioCompra_Producto']?>', '<?php echo $producto['PorcentajeDesc_Producto']?>', '<?php  echo $producto['Stock_Producto']?>')"><span class="plus close" ><i class="uil uil-plus"></i></span></a>
```

CODIGO FUNCION (ready y update son para actualizar la cantidad de producto, calcular el subtotal y el total):

```js
function agregarProducto(codigo, nombre, precio, descuento, stock) {
  ready();

  var rowCount = $("#sampleTbl tr").length - 1;

  $("#sampleTbl tbody").append(`
    <tr class="fila"">
    <td>${rowCount}</td>
    <td>${codigo}</td>
    <td>${nombre}</td>
    <td class="precio">${precio}</td>
    <td class="descuento">${descuento}</td>
    <td><input value="1" type="number" class="valor" max="${stock}" ></td>
    <td>${stock}</td>
    <td class="total">${precio}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminar(this)">Eliminar</button></td>
    </tr>
    `);

  updateTotal();
  ready();
}
```

Mi problema surge en que acabo de agregar nuevo codigo al JS con el cual busco evitar que se agrege el mismo producto mas de una vez en la tabla. Ya he conseguido que reconozca que un producto ya se agrego, pero el problema es que como el boton esta asociado directamente a la funcion de todos modos lo agrega. El codigo de esta funcionalidad es el siguiente:

```js
  var addCart = document.getElementsByClassName("agregar");

  for (var i = 0; i < addCart.length; i++) {

    var button = addCart[i];

    button.addEventListener('click', addCartClicked);

  }
  
  function addCartClicked(event) {

  var button = event.target;
  var shopProducts = button.parentElement;
  shopProducts = shopProducts.parentElement;
  shopProducts = shopProducts.parentElement;
  var nombre = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('prod-name')[0].innerText;
  var precio = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('prod-precio')[0].innerText;
  shopProducts = shopProducts.parentElement;
  console.log(shopProducts)
  var item = shopProducts.getElementsByClassName('product-img')[0];
  var img = item.getElementsByClassName('prod-img')[0].src;

  addProductToCart(img, nombre, precio);
  updateTotal();

}

function addProductToCart(img, nombre, precio) {

  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('product-item')[0];
  console.log(cartItems);
  var cartItemsContent = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('product-content')[0];
  var cartItemsNames = cartItemsContent.getElementsByClassName('prod-name');

  for (var i = 0; i < cartItemsNames.length; i++) {

    alert('Este producto ya esta agregado al carrito')
    return;

  }

}
```

Lo que me gustaria es pasarle los parámetros al primer evento y, de esta forma, si no se ha agregado el producto lo pueda hacer o, por el contrario, si hay otra forma de realizar esto me gustaria que me la pudieran indicar.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Te presento dos opciones para lograr lo que quieres hacer

```js
// opción 1 con variable global que se puede ir cambiando según se necesite
let opt1Counter = 1;
const button1 = document.querySelector('#option1');

button1.addEventListener("click", func1);

function func1(event) {
  alert("option 1 pressed " + opt1Counter + " times");
  opt1Counter++;
}

// opción 2 con variable en el botón que se puede ir cambiando según se necesite
const button2 = document.querySelector('#option2');
button2.opt2Counter = 1; // este puede ser el nombre que quieras y la cantidad de parámetros que quieras
button2.addEventListener("click", func2);

function func2(event) {
  alert("option 2 pressed " + event.currentTarget.opt2Counter + " times");
  event.currentTarget.opt2Counter++;
}
```

```html
<button id="option1">option 1</button>
<button id="option2">option 2</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Me surgieron dos dudas: 1. Como hago para determinar si la persona quita de la tabla el producto y lo vuelve a agregar? 2. En que parte incluiría mi función para que se agregue el producto a la fila? Y una cosa que no dije es que son varios botones idénticos identificados con una clase

Comment: "cómo determinar si la persona quita un producto de la tabla" pues probablemente tengas un botón para quitar el producto, ahí es donde deberías determinarlo. "En qué parte incluiría función para agregar producto", no conozco todos los detalles de tu aplicación pero el orden debiese ser mas o menos así: llenar formulario producto o seleccionar producto, presionar botón agregar producto, comprobar si existe, si existe mostrar alerta y no agregar, si no existe agregar producto a tabla y actualizar

Comment: Ok, gracias. Lo probare y cualquier cosa te aviso :)

Answer (score 0):

Si agregas una id a la fila, y esta id es el código del producto, puedes lograr hacer una fila única por producto.

```
function agregarProducto(codigo, nombre, precio, descuento, stock) {

  let fila = document.getElementById("Fila_" + codigo);
  
  if(fila==null){ 
    //no existe producto, así que lo agregamos

    ready();

  var rowCount = $("#sampleTbl tr").length - 1;

  $("#sampleTbl tbody").append(`
    <tr class="fila" id="Fila_${codigo}">
    <td>${rowCount}</td>
    <td>${codigo}</td>
    <td>${nombre}</td>
    <td class="precio">${precio}</td>
    <td class="descuento">${descuento}</td>
    <td><input value="1" type="number" class="valor" max="${stock}" ></td>
    <td>${stock}</td>
    <td class="total">${precio}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminar(this)">Eliminar</button></td>
    </tr>
    `);

  updateTotal();
  ready();
  }
  else{
    //Existe producto, así que sumamos uno a cantidad
    //siempre y cuando no supere el stock
     
     let valorInput = fila.querySelector(".valor");
     let max = Number( valorInput .getAttribute("max"));
     let valor = Number(valorInput.value);

     if(valor+1<=max){
         valorInput.value = valor+1;
     }
    
  }
}
```